# How to get 'date,time' column from MySQL database as input to google chart DateRangeFilter?

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-visualization

I have a column which consists of a date-time value 'for example: 2017-2-2 10:30:20'. I want this rows used as an input to Date Range Filter in Google chart.
How can this be created? I have tried using an array of that column values, but that doesn't worked for me.

Comment: @WhiteHat I'm using php

Comment: This is MySQL database table ://
    //Timestamp  Name  Percentage
    //2017-1-2 10:23:32  A  50
    //2017-2-5 15:40:10 B  50

Now, I want to use this data to display in google pie chart along with range filter.
The columns 'Name' and 'Percentage' must be used for chart data while column 'Timestamp' must be used for fitering the pie chart i.e in DateRangeFilter.
How can this be achieved?
It is not accepting the date values as a range for DateRangeFilter.

Comment: @WhiteHat I have accepted the answer. Please upvote my question, if you have downvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's just using the standard javascript Date object. Easier method would be to get a `unix_timestamp(yourdatefield)` out of MySQL, which gives you seconds-since-the-epoch.

```
(example) mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-11-13 10:20:19');
        -> 1447431619
```

Javascript's date object accepts milliseconds-since-the-epoch as one initializer value, so:

```
data.addRow(new Date(<?php echo ($seconds_from_db) ?>000));
                                                 ^^^--- 3 extra zeroes to make it a millisecond value
```

To use the `unix_timestamp command`

```
select unix_timestamp(yourfield) as seconds
```

Comment: This is MySQL database table :
    //Timestamp  Name  Percentage
    //2017-1-2 10:23:32  A  50
    //2017-2-5 15:40:10 B  50

Now, I want to use this data to display in google pie chart along with range filter.
The columns 'Name' and 'Percentage' must be used for chart data while column 'Timestamp' must be used for fitering the pie chart i.e in DateRangeFilter.
How can this be achieved?
It is not accepting the date values as a range for DateRangeFilter

Comment: I think I gave you the solution my friend have you tried it ? What is wrong with that ?Do you have any errors ?If this answers your question please accept it

Comment: Can you tell me exactly, how can use unix timestamp function for my table?

Comment: What is not working give some info tell me what you tried ?

Comment: Thanks. I have accepted the answer. Its working. Please upvote my question if downvoted by you.